# How to make a view appear translucent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I'm using this to bring up a new view

```
[self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

This completely covers the original view. Is there a way to make the second view translucent so that parts of the original view can still be seen? Can it be done in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder you can make the background-color of the view clearColor and make sure there is a tick at Opaque.

Comment: I don't see a clear color option in IB. The opaque options doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I selected clear color, but when it is run in the simulator, it appears as white.

Answer (score 0):

I think, but not positive, that there is no easy way to make a modal view controllers view transparent. Im sure I needed to do this once but had to take a different approach. Would it be possible for you to just use a standard view and animate it as if it were a modal view controller?